# Непонятно или не понятно

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Не понятно, как это осуществить на самом деле, чтобы все реализовать через эту систему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для решения поставленной задачи обратимся **к правилу Розенталя.**
   Желательно в любом случае давать ссылку на правило, если возникают вопросы, так как именно правило является **объективным обоснованием** выбранной формы написания.

**Розенталь:** http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81

Слова категории состояния на -о (так называемые предикативные наречия) пишутся с частицей НЕ слитно **при утверждении**: *нетрудно видеть* и раздельно **при отрицании**: *не трудно видеть* (**смысл обычно устанавливается самим пишущим**).

Как мы видим, Розенталь предлагает нам два варианта решения, причем отрицание или утверждение может выбрать автор. Стилистических и семантических **запретов на выбор нет**, всё определяется по ситуации.

(1) **Непонятно,** как это осуществить на самом деле, чтобы все реализовать через эту систему. (2) **Не понятно,** как это осуществить на самом деле, чтобы все реализовать через эту систему.

2. **Для окончательного выбора** в этом случае желательно иметь контекст, по одному предложению судить сложно, в том числе давать негативную оценку одному из вариантов.

Если посмотреть на **частотность употребления  двух форм в Нацкорпусе,** то слитная форма используется значительно чаще, хотя отрицание тоже активно применяется. **Как обосновать такую статистику?** На уровне слов (непонятно и не понятно) формы не различаются, ведь в обоих случаях речь идет  об отсутствии ясности в чем-либо. В этом случае слитное написание является основным, а **раздельная** форма должна получить **дополнительное обоснование** в тексте.

3. Раздельное написание НЕ обозначает **выделенное отрицание.**  К примеру,  в тексте есть скрытое противопоставление: это понятно, а вот это нет. В этом случае отрицание желательно логически  подчеркнуть. Также раздельное письмо используется, если автор  хочет  выделить наречие **логическим ударением,** исходя из каких-то других причин.

Например, возможен такой контекст:   Что касается конструкции, то она  в принципе ясна. **Не  понЯтно**,  как это осуществить практически (подчеркивается отрицание при скрытом противопоставлении). **Не понЯтно** всё-таки, может ли вообще работать эта система (логическое подчеркивание наречия).

При отсутствии логического выделения  наречие пишется **слитно.** И это тоже решает автор.

5. Примеры с отрицанием (**все очень стилистически неопрятные и двусмысленные**). Остальные (такие же) можно посмотреть **у Розенталя)**.

**Не понятно**, откуда он взялся в конце июля, ― тополя уже месяц назад отцвели. [Михаил Елизаров (2009)]

**Не понятно,** куда клонил хитрый порученец. [Михаил Елизаров. Библиотекарь (2007)]

**Не понятно мне все это… Не-е, не понятно.** Как раз, человек очень был ответственный. [Владимир Дудинцев. (1987)]

—  **Понятно. Одно не понятно**. Откуда вы знаете, что он загадал 99? [Сергей Носов. Фигурные скобки (2015)]

**И не понятно**, кто из них мужчина, а кто женщина. [Маша Трауб. Плохая мать (2010)]

Comment: *Не согласен я.*

Comment: Артем, тогда проголосуйте ниже, если вы МОЛЧА не согласны. Если можете что-нибудь сказать, то я вас внимательно слушаю (но только  сегодня). И желательно не личные впечатления на слух, а что-нибудь объективное, убедительное.

Comment: Ну я считаю, что все ваши раздельные примеры лучше в слитном варианте. Все идеи, что "отрицание хорошо логически подчеркнуть" я одобряю теоретически, но на практике не вижу, чтобы какое-то подчёркивание оправдывало раздельное написание. При слитном написании логическое ударение также может падать на наречие (непонЯтно) и *непонятно,* чем "не понЯтно" в этом случае лучше. Вот если найдётся пример с "нЕ понятно" (с ударением на частицу), тогда я, пожалуй, одобрю раздельное написание в таком случае.

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо! За смелость и искренность!

Answer (score 5):

Пор смыслу тут должно быть слитное написание.

***Непонятно, как это осуществить на самом деле...***

Раздельное написание ("не понятно, как...") не будет явной орфографической ошибкой, но фраза становится стилистически неопрятной и несколько двусмысленной: что-то типа "не понятно, но очевидно". Если автор не претендует на какую-то оригинальность, то вариант с раздельным написанием лучше не использовать.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий для Артема**

Спасибо, Артем, теперь мне всё ясно, хотя и очень грустно тоже.  Пожалуй, мне нечего больше делать на  этом форуме.  Я с большой вероятностью могу предположить, что **интонационную теорию не понимает никто**, в прямом смысле этого слова. Тогда зачем я уже почти пять лет рассказываю про интонацию, если результат нулевой. Это все равно что читать книгу на никому не известном языке. Слушатели кивают головой, иногда соглашаются из вежливости,  но всё это, вероятно,  на уровне интуиции. Возможно, все, как и вы,  думают, что на частицу НЕ можно поставить ударение.

А теперь пару слово том, что такое **логическое ударение на практике**. Рассмотрим одно из предложений:  ***Не понятно, откуда он  (пух) взялся в конце июля.***
Запятая делит предложение на две  несимметричные части, поэтому произносим его так:  **Непонятно, / откуда он взЯлся /// в конце иЮля.**

Мы делим предложение на две фразы,  причем наречие относим к первой части.  **Позиция у наречия безударная.** Мы выделяем его голосом и даже делаем небольшую паузу, но основное тоническое ударение  ставим в другом месте – в конце каждой фразы.  **Логического ударения здесь вообще нет.** Это наша **естественная** речь, мы нисколько не напрягаем голос.

А теперь произнесем предложение с логическим выделением наречия.  **Не понЯтно, / откуда он взЯлся /// в конце иЮля.**

Наше предложение делится уже на три фразы, и мы делаем **три, а не два**  ударения, причем первое ударение дополнительное **усиливаем голосом**, да и **паузу** можем увеличить.  Всё это делается для того чтобы выделить наречие, причем сделать это можно не в любой позиции.  Именно   поэтому для  начала предложения характерны варианты со слитным и раздельным написанием НЕ – здесь удобно перестроить интонацию.

Поэтому логическое ударение – это не ударение на частицу НЕ, **наша частица всегда безударная**. Логическое выделение ударением  – это **целый комплекс фонетических приемов.**

И вот что я хочу еще сказать **в завершение темы.**  Не надо думать, что мы написали **НЕ раздельно – и вот уже обозначили отрицание.**  Это всё только на бумаге, а мы должны слышать это в устной речи. Одними фонетическими средствами обойтись сложно, поэтому в предложении обычно используются **формальные признаки**: противопоставление, усиление отрицания, другая дополнительная лексика и т.д. Наш собеседник  должен понимать нас – утверждаем мы что-либо или отрицаем.

А вам, Артем, моя огромная личная благодарность.  Вы **смелый человек без комплексов** и можете честно сказать, что именно вам непонятно, а это может сделать далеко не каждый.  Вот такая интересная получилась **сказка – про «голого короля».** Так что можно и улыбнуться тоже.

Кстати, сегодня пятница, 13-е число.

Comment: Много мыслей, не знаю, с чего начать. Хотел сказать, что до конца я, наверно, не понимаю, вашу теорию, но обычно понимал, насколько мог, и часто соглашался с этими интонационными выделениями: сам так же произношу. На НЕ я и не думаю, что в данном случае можно поставить ударение, просто я сказал, что если допустить такое, что его можно выделить, тогда бы я легче принял раздельное написание. Кстати, на НЕ может падать ударение в других случаях, например *не был, не дал.* В первом примере так все и говорят, во втором — в наше время уже мало кто делает ударение на НЕ. Закончу, не помещается.

Comment: Забыл обобщить: конечно, не зря вы этим занимались! Обычно интересно и полезно это читать, особенно когда видишь так же! Почему я против раздельного написания в этом случае? Я понимаю эти варианты разделения на две или три фразы, но даже если фразы три, я боюсь писать раздельно, потому что никогда с этим не сталкивался. Просто у нас это слово всегда сросшееся. И я привык (может, конечно, и неправильно) к тому, что даже когда делают логическое ударение на "не( )понятно", то пишут его слитно. И примеры из первого вашего ответа кажутся ошибочными.

Comment: Но всё может быть, вдруг вы в конце концов меня переубедите.

Answer (score 0):

"Совершенно непонятно" -- абсолютное утверждение не нуждающееся в каких-то уточнениях и компромиссах.
"Не понятно" - смещается акцент. Например, если написать "не вполне понятно" или же "никому не понятно", то появляется смысл именно в наличии глагола, как мне кажется. Таким образом, автор сам, подставив пару слов и представив звучание фразы, может дойти до подходящего его ощущению идеального варианта.