# Как относиться к слитному написанию "бестолку", которое встречается у классиков?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Кто-то задал интересный [вопрос](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=279023), а Грамота лишь отметила, что словари рекомендуют раздельное написание, но никак не прокомментировала ссылки на классику.

Comment: Если можно вставить вопрос или какое-то определение — это наречное сочетание, которое пишется раздельно. Без («чего?» или «всякого») толку.

Comment: @shampar Думаю, что классики не знали этого простого правила (если Вы поняли, в чём был вопрос Артёма).

Comment: Трудно понять, когда вопроса нет. В конкретном случае возвращение к нормальному предлогу было правильным. Отошли хоть на шажок от бесовщины.

Comment: @shampar: да есть же вопрос! В заголовке.

Comment: Вопроса нет и не может быть к классикам. Орфография менялась не ими, а национальной историей.

Comment: *классики не знали этого простого правила* - я думаю, им этого и не надо было. Это правило для запоминания, так сказать, для гимназистов, а не правило орфографии как таковое. Классики могли себе позволить исходить из других, более общих и более академических формулировок - наподобие той, что я привел в своем ответе. Правда, это уже современный подход, но и тогда явно не *правилом Shampar'а* "классики" пользовались.

Comment: @behemothus Да, зря я там не поставил смайлик.

Comment: Нет. Ваш смайлик подразумевался. Я ответил не потому, что там смайлика не было.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Такая оживленная дискуссия, столько пик понабросано, а вопрос — удивительно! — никем не отмечен. Надо это дело поправить.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, что положили почин! Мне очень приятно! :)

Answer (score 5):

Вот что писал Грот о предлогах ***воз, из, низ, раз, без, чрез***:

> …В слитном употреблении их перед безголосными *к, х, п, т, ф,* перед
> шипящими *ч, ш, щ* и перед *ц* пишут по произношению: *вос, ис, нис,
> рас…*
>
> Но правило изменять в названных предлогах *з* на *с* не
> расространяется на предлоги ***без*** и ***чрез***. Принято писать:
> *безконечный, безпечность, безчисленный, чрезполосный, черезчур.*

Не изменяли этому правилу и классики. И если бы они использовали слитное написание в этом наречии, то писали бы его, скорее всего, с *з*: *безтолку*.

Но слитно они его, похоже на то, не писали...

Из издания 1853 года комедии А.Н. Островского "Не в свои сани не садись":

> *Девку долго ли обмануть!.. Ветрогон какой-нибудь, прости Господи, подвернется, подластится; ну, девка и полюбит; так ее и отдавать **без
> толку**?..*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же — в раздельном написании— ***без толку*** печаталось и в "Мёртвых душах" Гоголя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант написания ***бестолку*** начал теснить ***без толку***, как видно из материалов Нацкорпуса, только после реформы русского правописания 1917 года. Такое написание вошло в качестве основного и в 4-томный толковый словарь Ушакова конца 30-х годов, вариант же ***без толку*** был дан Ушаковым в скобках после основного. Из числа существующих на тот момент написаний был выбран Ушаковым в качестве рекомендуемого именно слитный вариант ***бестолку*** и в школьном орфографическом словаре 1938 года (см. комментарии ниже). Но в 6-ом издании этого же школьного словаря (1944 г.) ***бестолку*** уже нет — этот вариант был заменён при переиздании словаря на ***без толку***…

Вот что говорилось Ушаковым в предисловии к первому изданию школьного словаря, воспроизведённом в издании 1944 года:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окончательно же норма правописания этого наречия в виде ***без толку*** была узаконена в 1956 году.  Вариант же ***бестолку***, получивший распространение во времена Ушакова, стал снабжаться словаристами пометой *"устар."*...

Comment: *только уже после реформы русского правописания 1917 года*  - господь с Вами. В нацкорпусе изрядно примеров "бестолку" из XIX века - и раньше.

Comment: *И если бы они использовали слитное написание в этом наречии, то писали бы его с з: безтолку* - это правило (вернее исключение) совершенно не соблюдалось до Грота, да и нем - не очень.

Comment: _behemothus: только уже после реформы русского правописания 1917 года - господь с Вами. В нацкорпусе изрядно примеров "бестолку" из XIX века - и раньше._ === Вы не правы! Есть, по-моему, **только** два примера — из Успенского и Островского. Второй из них опровергается тем фото, что я привёл в ответе.  Нацкорпус отцифровал не те издания, что были в 19 веке, а издание 40-х годов ХХ века, в котором имевшее место у Островского написание было отредактировано под словарь Ушакова. Пользоваться Нацкорпусом нужно очень осторожно!

Comment: очень сомнительно, что "оцифровали" издания именно 40-го года, не раньше - не позже.

Comment: Кстати, оба ваших примера - на другое значение "без толку", в них "толк" - не потеряло своего значения как существительное.

Comment: Вот насчет количества примеров в нацкорпусе - это да. Извините, глюкнуло. но где-то я их видел... И даже у Пушкина, кажется. Я найду.

Comment: Ой, сообразил. Это не про "бестолку" примеры были, совсем по другому поводу. Извините еще раз, заскок, два дела сразу делал - вот результат. . Но в целом-то вопрос не снимается. Утвреждение о том, что написание "бестолку" противоречит правилам  старого Грота пока неубедительно.

Comment: _behemothus: Кстати, оба ваших примера - на другое значение "без толку", в них "толк" - не потеряло своего значения как существительное._ === behemothus, Вы меня _улыбнули_. Я привёл ссылки именно на те примеры, на которые ведь и ссылался Артём, говоря, что _классики_ писали в этих примерах слитно "бестолку". Оказалось, что эти классики писали в этих примерах совсем не так, как думал Артём.

Comment: _behemothus: Утверждение о том, что написание "бестолку" противоречит правилам старого Грота пока неубедительно_ === Пожалуйста, прочитайте ещё раз в моём ответе цитату из Грота!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень интересно, что на самом деле по-другому хотя бы у Гоголя. Я в принципе допускал это, просто не знал, где проверить.

Comment: Поддержал ответ, но добавил к своему пару ссылок из древности на слитное написание. Любопытно, что у Даля параллельно употреблялось "без[c]толку" (с обозначенным ударением на первом слоге) и "безъ толку".

Comment: @slava1947 Просто для сведения: в орфографическом словаре 1938 года (для начальной, неполной средней и средней школы; проф. Д. Н. Ушаков) — бе́столку, _нареч._ Без какого-либо другого варианта.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова:  _Просто для сведения: в орфографическом словаре 1938 года (для начальной, неполной средней и средней школы; проф. Д. Н. Ушаков) — бе́столку, нареч. Без какого-либо другого варианта._ ===
Спасибо, Римма Михайлова, за информацию!  В 38-ом было "бестолку" — а в 44-м году, в 6-ом издании этого же школьного словаря — уже "без толку". И тоже без вариантов. Т.е. вариант "бестолку" имел предпочтительность очень недолгое время.

Comment: + По поводу вариантов... Я в ответе, говоря о варианте в скобках, имел в виду 4-томный толковый словарь Ушакова. В  школьном же словаре их и не должно было быть: Ушаков в предисловии к 1-му изданию писал, что избирает в этом словаре "из числа существующих, конечно, грамотных, написаний одно — то, которое представляется наиболее распространённым в настоящее время".

Comment: Я уже проголосовала за Ваш ответ (и, естественно, менять ничего не собираюсь). Прошу только внести уточняющее изменение: _Такое написание вошло в качестве основного и в **толковый** словарь Ушакова конца 30-х годов..._ (Во избежание вопросов или (как в моем комментарии) уточнений — о каком именно словаре идет речь.)

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, постарался сейчас как-то уточнить свой ответ с учётом Вашего замечания... Спасибо Вам за помощь! 

Comment: О-и... И Вам спасибо за добрые слова и букетик. (Честное слово, расплылась, растрогалась — "прям вдрызг"!) Слава (надеюсь, я могу так обращаться), у меня к Вам просьба: не могли бы Вы привести **полностью** цитату из предисловия в первому изданию словаря Ушакова — конечно же, с соблюдением **той** орфографии и пунктуации. Хочу задать вопрос — а первого издания в интернете не нашла. (У меня только пятое (1938; мамино — _Михайловой Риммы, 6"а" кл., 1946 г._) и восьмое (1952; с Крючковым)).

Comment: @ Римма Михайлова. == Гм... Воспроизвести в своём ответе? Или послать Вам на почту? У меня, кстати, самого этого издания нет, но в 6-м, на который я ссылался, это предисловие (к 1-му издания) приводится. Скорее всего, оно должно было бы быть и в 5-м издании, что есть у Вас. Похоже на то, что Вас что-то смутило в процитированном мной предложении из предисловия... Наверное, запятая после "конечно"?

Comment: Уфф! Значит, можно  — _Слава_?! (Да можно и в комментарии показать — пока модераторы не прикрыли. Надо почту? Дам. Только я очень редко ее использую.) Вот что есть в пятом (печатном) издании: «В отличие от других справочников подобного типа я избегаю давать двоякие написания слов (например, _идти_ и _итти_), а избираю из числа существующих, конечно грамотных, написаний одно то, которое представляется наиболее распространённым в настоящее время». Ведь есть же **разница** — или я придумываю?

Comment: _Слава?_  Конечно можно! Так меня все и зовут.  А вот по поводу предисловия... Не знаю, почему в 6-м издании была изменена пунктуация... Но, к сожалению, так оно и было. Постараюсь сейчас сфотографировать этот фрагмент и, если получится, ввести его в свой ответ.

Comment: Признательна Вам, Слава, за изыскания. Задала свой вопрос (каюсь — со ссылкой на Вашу информацию). Если интересно — взгляните.

Answer (score 2):

> То есть старое написание исключительно как в заголовке, да?

Тут трудно делать однозначные выводы. Видимо так: "cтарое" написание предполагало слитный вариант, но только в том случае, когда очевидно наречное значение слова. Да и то с той оговоркой, что до Грота единого кодифицируещего источника не существовало вовсе, все определялось традицией, а правила Грота таковым источником являлись лишь по факту, официального статуса им никто не придавал. Кстати, в XVII веке писали и *безтолку*, правила о переходе З в С не существовало.

На основании очень беглого анализа могу сказать, что написание *бестолку* встречается главным образом в источниках до середины XIX века и уже современных, XXI века. Про старое написание уже сказал, трудно рассуждать определенно, а современное нормативное "без толку" базируется на том принципе, что наречия, образованные элементом "без" (и некоторыми другими приставками-предлогами) и существительным, не утрачивающим в таком сочетании исходного значения, пишутся раздельно. Само по себе это положение как некое кодифицирующее правило не годится, ибо содержит не до конца формализуемое представление о сохранении исходного значения существительного, но для понимания общего подхода, да и как этакая шпаргалка-орфограмка, вполне пригодно.  Частое появление написания *бестолку* у современных авторов, видимо, объясняется тем, что в их понимании существительное "толк" выходит из употребления и таким образом образованное от него наречие не подпадает под сформулированное правило-орфограмку.

Не уверен, что помогло разобраться, я и сам вопрос-то до конца не понял, но чем могу.

(+)
Интересное дело... В нацкорпусе огромное число вхождений "без толку" из источников XIX века, но все более - в особом, необычном для современного языка употреблении.

> *Необыкновенная пестрота лиц привела его в совершенное замешательство; ему казалось, что какой-то демон искрошил весь мир на множество разных кусков и все эти куски без смысла, без толку смешал вместе*
> [Н. В. Гоголь. Невский проспект (1835)]

Здесь-то явно не наречие.

А те несколько примеров, где "без толку" несмотря на наречное значение написано раздельно, могут быть следствием редактирования под современную орфографию. В общем, вопрос о тогдашней орфографии не закрыт, хотя очевидно, что написание "бестолку" было как минимум допустимым в условиях определенного контекста.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень интересно! А после "значения существительного" смайлик или лишняя скобочка?))

Comment: Скобочка лишняя. спасибо. хотел сначала все пояснение в скобки забрать - потом передумал, да не до конца вычистил.

Answer (score 2):

Второй ответ

Как относиться к слитному написанию наречия «***бестолку***» у классиков? **Я думаю, что относиться надо с пониманием.** Тогда не было строгой регламентации письма, которая была введена только в 1956 году. Соответственно, не все понимали, почему вообще существуют два варианта. **Можно задать вопрос: а сейчас мы это понимаем, это в учебниках объясняется?**  Почему могут писаться  раздельно даже те наречия, которые не употребляются без предлога?

Попробуем рассмотреть очень известную пару:  ***держать в тайне – надеяться втайне.***  В этой паре мы противопоставляем **предметное** значение  существительного и **обстоятельственное** значение наречия. Значит, **причина** разного письма –  это существование **двух форм с разным значением**. Эта задача объясняется в правилах и изучается в школе.

Но есть задачи и посложнее:  когда надо просто **исключить** предметное понимание существительного или  когда надо **противопоставить** два разных обстоятельственных значения

**Пример 1.**  Наречие ***напрокат***

Мы пишем слитно: *взять что-либо **напрокат***. Слово ***прокат*** существует в современном языке, существовало и раньше.

Так я и воротился домой, не солоно хлебавши и только потратив 1 1/ 2 руб. **за прокат** шпаги и треугольной шляпы. [А. М. Достоевский. (1896)]

При этом прошу: уведомь, если изменишь день приезда, чтобы мне даром не разоряться **на прокат** парадной формы. [Ал. П. Чехов. Письма Антону Павловичу Чехову (1899)]

Мы видим у Чехова вполне обоснованное раздельное написание:  разоряться (на что?) – ***на прокат***  – **предметное** значение. А вот взять (как?) ***напрокат*** уже тогда писалось  слитно, хотя и не всегда:

Чтобы угодить тебе, явлюсь в парадной форме, которую возьму **напрокат** у сторожа [А. П. Чехов. (1899)]

…я послал взять в соседней лавке **на прокат** новую циновку, чтобы устлать пол из битой глины. [А. А. Рафалович. (1850)]

Глагол ***взять*** с предлогом НА может иметь два разных значения, которые нужно различать. Для сравнения:  *взять  (как?) напрокат  – взять (зачем?)  на воспитание.* Поэтому слитное написание  «взять напрокат»  исключает понимание действия  в качестве направленного (**целевого**).

**Пример 2.** Наречие ***вброд***.

В современной орфографии закреплено написание «*перейти реку **вброд***», а вот раньше  писали по-разному:

Лена в сём месте не шире иногда 30 и 50 сажен, летом очень мелка, и везде ездят **вброд**. [А. Н. Радищев. Записки путешествия в Сибирь (1790)]

Прежде Ключевую  нужно было только в лодке переплывать, а теперь переехали **в брод**, вода едва хватала лошади по брюхо. [Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Хлеб (1895)]

*БРОД*, м. Мелкое место во всю ширину реки, озера и т.п., удобное для перехода, переезда. Можно зайти (куда?) – ***в брод***, но переходить надо (как?)–  ***вброд***. Одно обстоятельственное значение **противопоставлено** другому.

**Пример 3**. Наречие ***без толку***

Почему практически все наречия с предлогом  БЕЗ пишутся **раздельно**? БЕЗ – предлог, который указывает на отсутствие кого-, чего-л.  ***Без толку*** – это значит напрасно, без видимого результата. Слитная форма письма **ничего не изменит**, в ней **нельзя усмотреть нового смысла** – ни предметного, ни обстоятельственного. Поэтому даже в значении наречия это существительное пишется раздельно с предлогом БЕЗ, сохраняя свое падежное управление.

Также материал о написании этого наречия есть в вопросе [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462651/Можно-ли-установить-закономерность-в-написании-наречий](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462651/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Мне удалось найти настолько ценный источник по вопросам слитного/раздельного написания наречий, что я решил выделить для него новый ответ (на который смогу ссылаться в будущем).

В работе О.Е. Ивановой ["Правописание наречий: правила и словарь"](http://rjano.ruslang.ru/ru/archive/2007-2/147-163) подробно описана история вопроса, даны и объяснены многочисленные правила и исключения, представлены и аргументированы различные точки зрения. Хорошо бы скопировать всю эту работу в ответе, но там всё же 17 страниц, поэтому ограничусь только ссылкой.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! У меня есть расширенный вариант (более 40 страниц) этой статьи Ольги Евгеньевны в бумажной книге "Лингвистические основы кодификации русской орфографии". Но в электронном виде не было...

Comment: Лень всё это читать, но большое спасибо за старания! Круто!

Answer (score 1):

А что здесь удивительного? Десятки, если не больше, наречий изменили своё написание со слитного на раздельное и наоборот с середины прошлого века. Понятно, что в словарях Даля и Ушакова, например, всё было, как у классиков.

**Дополнение**.
Добавлю пару ссылок из древности для пользы общей объективности в этой теме.

[Слитное написание с "бес" до 1917 г.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83%22&client=firefox-b-d&biw=1138&bih=506&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1917&tbm=bks)
Как видим, такое написание гугло-книги находят только в многочисленных изданиях словаря Даля (в каждом издании несколько вхождений, иногда с указанием ударения на первом слоге). Следует отметить, что в этих же изданиях одновременно встречается и "безъ толку" (примерно в таких же количествах).

[Слитное написание с "без" до 1917 г.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83%22&client=firefox-b-d&biw=1138&bih=506&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1917&tbm=bks)
Здесь уже примеров побольше. Среди них также одно из изданий словаря Даля (тоже с ударением и с параллельным употреблением раздельного написания).

Comment: То есть старое написание исключительно как в заголовке, да?

Comment: Ну да, наверное (хотя за сильно старое не поручусь :)

Answer (score 1):

**Современная орфография**

Раздельно пишется большое количество наречий, которые  называют **наречными выражениями** или  обстоятельственным существительными: *соскочить на ходу, попробовать на вкус, сказать в насмешку.*

Основным признаком для раздельного написания наречных выражений является наличие **падежного управления**.

Раздельно могут писаться даже те наречия, которые **не употребляются без предлога** – в этом случае наличие падежного управления имеет преимущественное значение: *на дыбы, на попятную, на побегушках, на убой, с лихвой, с ведома,  во всеуслышание, во всеоружии, по старинке, не по нутру.*

**А как писали раньше?**

К примеру, в большинстве случаев  раздельно пишутся наречия с предлогами БЕЗ и ДО, причем **это не новая орфографии** – так писали и в XIX веке. Слитное написание этих предлогов встречается очень редко. Разные формы письма можно объяснить: в то время не было такой строгой регламентации, которая была введена в 1956 году.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса** (частотность раздельного и слитного написания)

**Наречие БЕЗ ТОЛКУ** (265:2)

От него мы ездили к Витте, часа полтора ― **без толку**, конечно.  [Максим Горький. Письма (1889-1906)]

Вятские крестьяне утверждают, что их лошади сами чувствуют, когда не следует рваться и тратить свои силы **бестолку**.  [Г. И. Успенский. (1889)]

**Наречие ДО УПАДУ** (140:5)

В этот день фея была очень весела: танцевала, как говорится, **до упаду** и пела без конца. [Д. В. Григорович (1893)]

Очень уж постарался Илья Фирсыч. Купцы хохотали **доупаду**. [Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк (1895)]

Comment: О, Sharon! А чего вы в том диалоге не ответили? Мне, кстати, на недавний вопрос тоже никто не ответил. :(

Comment: Артем,  если вы о нашем последнем разговоре, то вы меня, пожалуйста,  извините: просто я вообще ничего не читала после своей последней записи. Хотелось закрыть эту страницу, никогда не открывать и начать всё заново: ничего не помню, никого не знаю.  Поэтому, вернувшись через некоторое время на форум, я просто погасила все фонарики, красные и зеленые. А как мне еще  стать «новым участником»?  Даже если я забуду сразу всё (логин, почту и пароль), система мне об этом любезно напомнит.

Comment: Простите, если это из-за меня! Это было [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462472/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be/462495#comment478494_462495). Простите, утром увидел, как появился ваш ответ, но некогда было читать и пока ещё времени нету на это и на то, чтобы прочитать все комментарии и ответы. Если ответите мне на вопрос про падеж, как время будет, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Артем, это не из-за вас, это всё из-за них. Кого я имею в виду?  Да я и сама не знаю, но кто-то ведь виноват. Шутка, конечно!  Но  предлагать интонационные решения я по возможности больше не буду, постараюсь всё переводить на грамматический язык. Может быть, и не хуже получится. А где вопрос про падеж, я не понимаю, сформулируйте его еще раз.

Comment: @Sharon  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462563/Не-дотянул-управление

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Спасибо за подсказку.  И еще  за то, что оставили открытым  недавний вопрос, там как раз одного голоса не хватало. Артем, я помотрю, когда будет время.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: спасибо!) И вам, Sharon, большое спасибо заранее! Как это голоса не хватало? О чём это речь? Интонационные решения я всегда понимал и только в последний раз не согласился, а так мне всегда казалось это убедительным и что вы правы. Так что лучше продолжайте. ;)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Одного голоса не хватало для закрытия вопроса.  И он пока открыт: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462627/Помогите-определиться-со-знаками-препинания-в-предложении

Comment: Я отозвал свой голос за закрытие. В спешке тогда проголосовал, потому что автор не дал своего варианта и не привёл никаких рассуждений.