# Можно ли установить закономерность в написании наречий?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, наречия

**Цитата из научной статьи**: "Применение ко всей совокупности наречий  какого-либо  единого  системного  основания  орфографической  классификации **представляется не адекватным** положению дел".

Адрес статьи: http://rjano.ruslang.ru/ru/archive/2007-2/147-163  О. Е. Иванова
Правописание наречий: правила и словарь.

Кажется, автор научной статьи утверждает, что установить закономерность в правописании наречий нельзя, **но мне это кажется странным**. Вот Менделеев сумел создать единую классификацию химических элементов, Карл Линней создал классификацию растений, современные физики работают над теорией единого поля, а здесь всего-то **классификация наречий по способу письма**.

1. Я считаю, что классифицировать наречия  с точки зрения слитного или раздельного написания **следует по способу образования,** причем это естественный способ, основанный на грамматике. Всего-то и надо определить **мотивирующее слово и сам способ**, и вот уже ясно, что перед нами – приставка со слитным написанием или предлог, который пишется раздельно. **Примечание**. Конечно, надо вспомнить, что предлог используется при падежном управлении и относится к существительным, местоимениям и другим частям речи, употребленным в значении существительных.
2. Соответственно, основные проблемы возникают для наречий, **мотивированных существительными**. Но и здесь не так уж всё сложно. Прежде всего, в русском языке существует большое количество **обстоятельственных существительных (наречных выражений)**. Это не наречия, а обычные падежные формы существительных с раздельным написанием предлогов. Чтобы выделить этот класс, надо взять, к примеру, Грамматику-80 и проверить **значение падежей**. К сожалению, эти значения не изучаются в школе, где много чего изучается, но вот на падежи своего родного языка там времени не хватает. К примеру, основным значением В.п. является **направленность**, при этом можно выделить частные значения: **ориентации,  результата, следствия, цели**.

**Примеры наречных выражений:** в меру, в ногу, на износ, под уклон; в струнку, в ряд, в прах, на славу; в заключение, в придачу, в насмешку, в новинку, на зависть, на вкус;  в розницу, в складчину, в рассрочку, в срок, на время; на скаку, на лету, на плаву, на бегу, на виду; по памяти; с ходу, с размаху, с разбегу, с изнанки, от силы; за границей.

3. К этому же классу относится наречие ***без толку*** из недавнего вопроса, которое в действительности является обстоятельственным существительным (Р.п., предлог БЕЗ). Почему до 1956 года встречалось его слитное написание? Вероятно, раньше считалось, что обстоятельственное значение – это причина для перехода в наречие. Но это не так, падежные формы существительного часто выполняют функцию наречия, но пишутся раздельно. Для перехода в наречие нужен **особый повод**, и таким поводом часто становится наличие **парных вариантов** с предметным и обстоятельственным значением.
4. Поэтому нас прежде всего будут интересовать **наречия со слитным написанием**, мотивированные существительными. Для них важен именно способ образования. Основной вариант – это **переход** существительного с предлогом в наречие (в тайне – втайне, на удачу – наудачу, в праве – вправе и т.д.). В отличие от существительного, которому глагол задает определенный падеж, наречие более свободно в образовании различных словосочетаний (держать в тайне – втайне желать, мечтать, надеяться, подыскивать, гордиться и др.).
5. Возьмем, к примеру, наречия ***поистине, поневоле***.  Наверное, в этом случае сложно подобрать парный вариант словосочетания с раздельным письмом, но и это не проблема, ведь **способ образования тот же самый. Иногда слитная форма позволяет менять** значение наречного выражения, как в слове ***напрокат*** (исключается целевая направленность и утверждается способ действия). Значительная группа наречий со слитным написанием  связана **с отглагольными существительными** (наперебой, наперехват, напоказ), которые, как правило, пишутся слитно.

Полагаю, что дальше продолжать не стоит, это уже частные детали. Мне же интересно узнать **ваше мнение** по поводу сложности классификации наречий по способу написания. Это действительно сложно и почему?

И еще **дополнительный вопрос по поводу цитаты**. Я, конечно, понимаю, что это научный стиль и всё такое, но и в этом случае, вероятно, действуют правила общей стилистики. Можно ли повысить **информативность** этого высказывания и исправить **стилистические погрешности**, если такие имеются?

Обсуждение вопроса о написании наречия "без толку" [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462623/Как-относиться-к-слитному-написанию-бестолку-которое-встречается-у-классиков](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462623/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: "Wитату из научной статьи" надо бы атрибутировать. Кто сказал, где сказал, когда сказал. Иначе не очень понятно, зачем сказал. а что касается самого вопроса, то он выглядит надуманным. Кодифицированная орфография (наречий в частности) сама по себе является порождением некой классификации словарных слов. То есть написание вторично по отношению к классификации, которую явно или неявно вводят авторы орфографических словарей. И как можно в такой ситуации говорить о обратном - классификации на основе правописания - я просто не понимаю.

Comment: Это статья  приводится в качестве примера из недавнего обсуждения  наречия «без толку» .  Речь идет именно о проблемах орфографии,  и даже употреблен термин «орфографическая классификация». Поэтому мой вопрос  непосредственно связан с темой этой статьи. Адрес вопроса: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462623/Как-относиться-к-слитному-написанию-бестолку-которое-встречается-у-классиков
Адрес статьи: http://rjano.ruslang.ru/ru/archive/2007-2/147-163  О. Е. Иванова
Правописание наречий: правила и словарь.

Comment: А я не вижу смысла противопоставлять по написанию наречие "бестолку" конструкции "без толку": они различаются как по употреблению, так и ударением. Грубо говоря, "бе́столку (=бесполезно) их противопоставлять, можно заниматься этим долго и без то́лку (=без результата)". Видимо, в какой-то момент произошла административная унификация того и другого в "бе́з толку".

Comment: Alex_ander, вы всё очень правильно понимаете, только делаете с точностью наоборот. Если нет разницы между слитным и раздельным письмом по значению, то нужно оставить эти слова в покое, то есть в их изначальном статусе - обстоятельственное существительное с раздельным написанием, что и было сделано. Иначе весь список наречных выражений, приведенный в ответе, тоже надо писать слитно или - что еще хуже -  писать как скажут.

Comment: Было бы прекрасно, если голосующие озвучили свое имя и свою позицию по данному вопросу. Иначе мне трудно понять, против чего или за что они голосуют: против меня лично; против статьи О. Ивановой как таковой или против ее содержания; а может быть, против метода, который я предлагаю. Особенно интересно пследнее - конструктивная критика всегда полезна автору. На комментарий Alex_ander я ответила, вы хотите что-нибудь добавить? Пожалуйста, представьтесь, и я внимательно вас выслушаю.

Comment: @Sharon  О каких голосах против идет речь? Я пока вижу только свой голос за.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, за ваш голос, для меня важна ваша поддержка. Я говорю про голосование в комментариях. Вот говорится, что  вопрос выглядит надуманным, и люди за это голосуют, хотя в этом случае надо считать и статью Ивановой надуманной. Вот я ответила Alex_ander, но ответ не понят и не принят - это критика в мой адрес, значит, что-то не так с предлагаемым методом. Мне же интересно знать, что именно кажется некорректным. Почему у нас не принято открытое обсуждение, когда ясно, кто говорит и что говорит?