# О предисловии к орфографическому словарю Ушакова

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, единственное-множественное-число, лексикография

[ПРЕДИСЛОВИЕ к 1-му ИЗДАНИЮ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462623/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) (так — в словаре):

> В отличие от других справочников подобного типа я избегаю давать двоякие написания слов (например *идти* и *итти*), а избираю из числа существующих, конечно, грамотных, написаний одно — то, которое представляется наиболее распространённым в настоящее время.

**Предисловие к пятому изданию** (подписано к печати с матриц 23.12.1937 г.; имеющийся экземпляр):

> В отличие от других справочников подобного типа я избегаю давать двоякие написания слов (например, *идти* и *итти*), а избираю из числа существующих, конечно грамотных, написаний одно то, которое представляется наиболее распространённым в настоящее время.

Словарь одного автора, а пунктуация в предисловии — разная.
И ещё: *двояк**ие** написан**ия*** или *двояк**ое** написан**ие***?
Подскажите, **как же правильно** написать это предложение?

P. S. Признательна участнику ***@slava1947*** за предоставленную информацию!

Answer (score 1):

Вы имеете в виду выделение вводного слова ***конечно***? Я думаю, это уже корректоры откорректировали в соответствии с более строгими правилами пунктуации, в связи с рекомендацией необособления вводного слова в начале любого оборота, а здесь явное уточнение, поэтому и убрали запятую. Наука развивается, появляются новые требования, а это научный справочник, он должен выглядеть безупречно грамотным, современным.

```
     двоякие написания или двоякое написание?
```

Значение слова «написание» по Словарю русского языка под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. 1999:

> • НАПИСА́НИЕ, -я, ср.
>
> 1. Действие по знач. глаг. написать. Сергей Иванович рассчитывал до подробности время, нужное на написание рецензии. Л. Толстой, Анна
>    Каренина.
> 2. Форма буквы в письме. Двоякое написание букв „д“ и „т“.
> 3. Буквенная передача звуков, слогов, слов. Правильное написание слов.

Источник  https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 электронная библиотека

Нас интересует третье значение.

Словарь лингвистических терминов Розенталя:

> написание
>
> Буквенное обозначение звукового состава слов.  В плане
> орфографическом различаются следующие типы написаний:
>
> 1. Написания
>    опорные. Написания, создаваемые по правилам графики на основе
>    произношения. ср.: дом — дым — дам — дум.
> 2. Написания проверяемые.
>    Написания, основанные на том, что звуки слабых позиций, чередующиеся в
>    составе той же морфемы со звуками сильных позиций, обозначаются теми
>    же буквами, как и последние.
> 3. Написания непроверяемые.
>    (беспроверочные). Написания, не допускающие проверки в связи с тем,
>    что звуки слабых позиций не чередуются в составе той же морфемы со
>    звуками сильных позиций. В этих случаях написания устанавливаются в
>    так называемом словарном порядке.
>
> По отношению к произношению различаются;
>
> 1. Написания фонетические. Написания, соответствующие произношению.
>    Сады,
>    давно, бок. см. фонетические написания.
> 2. Написания нефонетические.
>    Написания, не соответствующие произношению, расходящиеся с ним. Дрова,
>    пора, сапог.

Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/linguistics_rosenthal/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Так что это лингвистический термин, он употребляется и в ед., и во множ. числе

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила. Безусловно, и слово "конечно" я имела в виду. И еще слово "например". И еще вот эти конструкции: **написаний одно — то, которое** и **написаний одно то, которое**.

Comment: Например - тоже  следствие развития языка, приведение содержания справочника в соответствие с современными требованиями пунктуации (вводное слово  в начале оборота, заключённого в скобки,  отделяется запятой:), ведь в самом предисловии по Вашей последней ссылке написано:" В настоящем издании произведены небольшие изменения в соответствии с действующими языковыми нормами, а также сделан ряд добавлений за счет современной лексики".  Насчёт тире, я бы тоже поставила тире, чтобы уточнить, какое именно, но, видимо, корректор посчитал, что в научной речи не должно быть уточнений.Его право.

Comment: Обороты типа "в отличие от других справочников подобного типа" и вовсе факультативны, но он не так короток, я бы запятую тоже поставила (по современным языковым нормам). Так что предисловие к 5 изданию корректно для своего времени, а новые издания продолжают меняться в соответствии с новыми требованиями. Всё верно.

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите, **как же правильно** написать это предложение?

Если не менять состав слов, пунктуацию я бы выбрал примерно такую:

> В отличие от других справочников подобного типа я избегаю давать
> двоякие написания слов (например *идти* и *итти*), а избираю из числа
> существующих, конечно грамотных, написаний одно — то, которое
> представляется наиболее распространённым в настоящее время.

Или такую:

> В отличие от других справочников подобного типа я избегаю давать
> двоякие написания слов (например *идти* и *итти*), а избираю из числа
> существующих, конечно грамотных написаний, одно — то, которое
> представляется наиболее распространённым в настоящее время.

Ну а если бы писал сам, то убрал бы слово *конечно*:

> В отличие от других справочников подобного типа я избегаю давать
> двоякие написания слов (например *идти* и *итти*), а избираю из числа
> существующих грамотных написаний одно — то, которое представляется
> наиболее распространённым в настоящее время.

И ещё, может быть, заменил бы слово *двоякие* словом *вариативные*.

Comment: Вечер добрый, Слава (приятно — давно так ни к кому не обращалась — Слава). Спасибо! Правильно я поняла, что Вы выбрали единственный вариант вот здесь: **одно — то, которое**? А различия вокруг слова "например" Вас не смутили? А еще в некоторых изданиях есть вот тут запятая: _В отличие от других справочников подобного типа, я избегаю давать..._ (https://www.uchmag.ru/estore/e110785/) Как Вы к этому относитесь? P. S. Наверно, мне надо было обозначить все шесть проблемных мест в предложении. Но ведь это так громоздко.

Comment: Добый вечер, Римма! По поводу Ваших вопросов… 1). Отсутствие запятой после "например" я просто-напросто проглядел. Почему так произошло — не знаю. 2). После "В отличие от…" мне хотелось поставить запятую, но, заглянув в справочник по пунктуации, не стал этого делать. 3). Тире после "одно" в разбираемом предложении — для меня единственно возможный вариант.